# drupal 7.34 cannot rearrange form component and others

Tags: webforms

I have a fresh installation drupal 7.34 the install module ctools views and webformm. I cannot rearrange the form component. Both weight and the + symbol appear. Normally in the previous version I can switch using weight or drag the component to rearrange. How can I rearrange the form components. This problem also in other similar list, such as menu.

Comment: You've probably got a js error in your console. Take a look. This is often caused by using the wrong version of jQuery, a script error in a contrib module, or something getting messed up in the theme. Are you using a default admin theme?

Comment: Yes, create a new installation, the same problem. I found this "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" related to jquery.cookie. How to solve this problem ?

Comment: It's hard to tell where the error is creeping in. Draggable lists should work out the box. I'm not sure that jquery.cookie is a standard script. You could need to debug that. Webform and views aren't part of core either, so this can't be a "vanilla" install. I don't know what else you've installed on top of that, all of which could be contributing to the issue. This seems like more of a debugging issue than a specific question that can be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very lucky...., 
I found the answer to solve the problem (related to missing misc/jquery.cookie.js) from  this discussion https://www.drupal.org/node/1052372

To solve that: Configuration > Development, enable Aggregrate Javasript file

[image]

Now it just works perfectly as in the previous versions. Thanks Drupal developers.